# Python: How to parse a string representation of a numpy array to a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, parsing

I have a string representation of a numpy array that I want to parse into an numpy array. Any way on how to do this? I tried using this built-in `np.fromstring(X, dtype=int, sep=',')` but it doesn't seem to apply here.

```
'[0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.01,0.07,\n 0.07,0.07,0.49,0.53,0.68,0.1 ,0.65,1.  ,0.96,0.5 ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.12,0.14,0.37,0.6 ,0.66,0.99,\n 0.99,0.99,0.99,0.99,0.88,0.67,0.99,0.95,0.76,0.25,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.19,0.93,0.99,0.99,0.99,0.99,0.99,\n 0.99,0.99,0.99,0.98,0.36,0.32,0.32,0.22,0.15,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.07,0.86,0.99,0.99,0.99,0.99,0.99,\n 0.77,0.71,0.96,0.94,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.31,0.61,0.42,0.99,0.99,0.8 ,\n 0.04,0.  ,0.17,0.6 ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.05,0.  ,0.6 ,0.99,0.35,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.54,0.99,0.74,\n 0.01,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.04,0.74,0.99,\n 0.27,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.14,0.94,\n 0.88,0.62,0.42,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.32,\n 0.94,0.99,0.99,0.46,0.1 ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.18,0.73,0.99,0.99,0.59,0.11,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.06,0.36,0.98,0.99,0.73,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.97,0.99,0.97,0.25,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.18,0.51,0.71,0.99,0.99,0.81,0.01,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.15,0.58,\n 0.89,0.99,0.99,0.99,0.98,0.71,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.09,0.45,0.86,0.99,\n 0.99,0.99,0.99,0.79,0.3 ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.09,0.26,0.83,0.99,0.99,0.99,\n 0.99,0.77,0.32,0.01,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.07,0.67,0.86,0.99,0.99,0.99,0.99,0.76,\n 0.31,0.04,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.21,0.67,0.88,0.99,0.99,0.99,0.99,0.95,0.52,0.04,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.53,0.99,0.99,0.99,0.83,0.53,0.52,0.06,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,\n 0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ,0.  ]'
```

Comment: "ast.literal_eval" can parse it to a Python list. From there you can convert it.

Comment: Thanks. Can it handle the `.`'s?

Comment: E. g. a "0." is interpreted as Python float by "literal_eval". It should work.

Comment: Try avoid this.  The string representation is not designed for parsing ease.

Comment: A hand-written version; `np.array([list(map(float, e.strip(',').split(','))) for e in data.replace(' ', '')[1:-1].split('\n')])`. This is not very efficient bu ast parsing should not be great too...